# Loop through word document with image and storing to SQL java

Tags: java, arrays

My document is consisted of fixed headers with contents including image in between. Currently using Apache poi, the aim is to store the content in between each header (including images) using Java. However, in this case the image’s position is an important part included in the text. How do I store and retrieve the image together with text in Java?

For example:
[image: example]

Comment: Please do not use external image links but use the link image functionality provided by StackOverflow. That site is crowded with ads and who knows what.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check this out: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)